# git-daemon: "unable to allocate any listen sockets on host (null) port 9418"

Tags: linux, git, daemon

On Debian squeeze, I'm getting the syslog error:

```
unable to allocate any listen sockets on host (null) port 9418
```

And I can't clone remotely, also.

The file `/etc/service/git-daemon/run`:

```
"$(git --exec-path)"/git-daemon --verbose --base-path=/var/cache/git --detach --syslog --reuseaddr --export-all
```

`netstat -l | grep git` output:

```
tcp        0      0 *:git                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:git                [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

I'm currently restarting services with the `sv start/stop` command line, and killing service process to ensure it got reloaded.

Maybe I'm missing something really stupid.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use ssh and skip the daemon? I'm doing that and using gitolite with no issues.

Comment: That's nice, but `ssh` doesn't allow anonymous access.

Comment: Exactly, I have to make it public.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that when you use `--listen` parameter of `git-daemon`, it will not complain about missing `host`...

Answer (score 1):

That kind of problem is a good accasion to remind ourselves that [`git daemon`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-daemon) comes with the options:

```
--init-timeout=<n>
```

> Timeout (in seconds) between the moment the connection is established and the client request is received (typically a rather low value, since that should be basically immediate).

```
--timeout=<n>
```

> Timeout (in seconds) for specific client sub-requests.
>   This includes the time it takes for the server to process the sub-request and the time spent waiting for the next client’s request.

That makes sure socket are available to be allocated, instead of being kept around, for a client who might not be there.

git 2.9.x+ (Q3 2016) will detect those cases sooner:

See [commit a43b68a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a43b68a196652a0c6b054ee4905ac98d1cdcbbb9) (25 May 2016) by [Eric Wong (`ele828`)](https://github.com/ele828).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a43b68a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a43b68a196652a0c6b054ee4905ac98d1cdcbbb9), 25 May 2016)</sup>

> ### `daemon`: enable `SO_KEEPALIVE` for all sockets
>
> When "`git daemon`" is run without `--[init-]timeout` specified, **a
>   connection from a client that silently goes offline can hang around
>   for a long time, wasting resources**.
>   The socket-level `KEEPALIVE` has been enabled to allow the OS to notice such failed connections.
>
> While `--init-timeout` and `--timeout` options exist and I've never
>   run `git daemon` without them, some users may forget to set them
>   and encounter hung daemon processes when connections fail.
>
> Enable **socket-level timeouts** so the kernel can send keepalive
>   probes as necessary to detect failed connections.

Answer (score 0):

Compare to git daemon set up, this can be easier:

- For public repository, put it to github
- For private repository, set up sshd/ssh can be easy to do.

The problem also happened once on my server.

There are two ways I use when clone from git://... can not work.

1, git over ssh, append the user's public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, then username/password is not required to access the repository:

```
git clone user@host:/path/to/git/repository/myproject.git
```

2, pust the repository under webserver's accessable directory, such as

```
/var/www/git
```

Make sure /var/www/ is accessable, for example it set to be apache httpd's doc root.  This let user to get it at least.